# LeetCode on Longest Palindromic Substring in Python

Tags: python, programming-challenge, strings, dynamic-programming, palindrome

This is a programming question from [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-palindromic-substring/):

> Given a string s, return the longest palindromic substring in s.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: s = "babad" Output: "bab" Note: "aba" is also a valid answer.

Below is my code that fails the following input because of "Time Limit Exceeded":

> "glwhcebdjbdroiurzfxxrbhzibilmcfasshhtyngwrsnbdpzgjphujzuawbebyhvxfhtoozcitaqibvvowyluvdbvoqikgojxcefzpdgahujuxpiclrrmalncdrotsgkpnfyujgvmhydrzdpiudkfchtklsaprptkzhwxsgafsvkahkbsighlyhjvbburdfjdfvjbaiivqxdqwivsjzztzkzygcsyxlvvwlckbsmvwjvrhvqfewjxgefeowfhrcturolvfgxilqdqvitbcebuooclugypurlsbdfquzsqngbscqwlrdpxeahricvtfqpnrfwbyjvahrtosovsbzhxtutyfjwjbpkfujeoueykmbcjtluuxvmffwgqjgrtsxtdimsescgahnudmsmyfijtfrcbkibbypenxnpiozzrnljazjgrftitldcueswqitrcvjzvlhionutppppzxoepvtzhkzjetpfqsuirdcyqfjsqhdewswldawhdyijhpqtrwgyfmmyhhkrafisicstqxokdmynnnqxaekzcgygsuzfiguujyxowqdfylesbzhnpznayzlinerzdqjrylyfzndgqokovabhzuskwozuxcsmyclvfwkbimhkdmjacesnvorrrvdwcgfewchbsyzrkktsjxgyybgwbvktvxyurufsrdufcunnfswqddukqrxyrueienhccpeuqbkbumlpxnudmwqdkzvsqsozkifpznwapxaxdclxjxuciyulsbxvwdoiolgxkhlrytiwrpvtjdwsssahupoyyjveedgqsthefdyxvjweaimadykubntfqcpbjyqbtnunuxzyytxfedrycsdhkfymaykeubowvkszzwmbbjezrphqildkmllskfawmcohdqalgccffxursvbyikjoglnillapcbcjuhaxukfhalcslemluvornmijbeawxzokgnlzugxkshrpojrwaasgfmjvkghpdyxt"

```
class Solution(object):

    def longestPalindrome(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: str
        """
        if len(s) == 0:
            return None
        if len(s) == 1:
            return s

        P = [[False]*len(s) for i in range(len(s))]

        for i in range(len(s)):
            P[i][i]   = True

        for i in range(len(s)-1):
            P[i][i+1] = (s[i]==s[i+1])

        for s_len in range(3,len(s)+1):
            for i in range(len(s)+1-s_len):
                P[i][i+s_len-1] = P[i+1][i+s_len-2] and (s[i]==s[i+s_len-1])

        ip = 0
        jp = 0
        max_len = 1

        for i in range(len(s)):
            for j in range(len(s)):
                if P[i][j] and j+1-i > max_len:
                    max_len = j+1-i
                    ip = i
                    jp = j 
                    continue

        return s[ip:jp+1]
```

I was trying to follow the following approach described in the site solution. Could anyone help to see how to make my code more efficient?

---

[image]

Comment: Would you like to see other solutions too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Disclaimer: Not a Code Reviewer

Here are some short comments though:

- You're looping though twice.
- That'd make it brute force.
- Brute force does usually fail for some medium and hard questions on LeetCode.

#### Alternative Solution

- Here we'd loop through once:

```
class Solution:
    def longestPalindrome(self, s):
        if len(s) < 1:
            return s

        def isPalindrome(left, right):
            return s[left:right] == s[left:right][::-1]

        left, right = 0, 1
        for index in range(1, len(s)):
            if index - right > 0 and isPalindrome(index - right - 1, index + 1):
                left, right = index - right - 1, right + 2
            if index - right >= 0 and isPalindrome(index - right, index + 1):
                left, right = index - right, right + 1
        return s[left: left + right]
```

[image]

#### Your Solution

- I just tested your solution (marginally passes):

```
class Solution(object):

    def longestPalindrome(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: str
        """
        if len(s) < 1:
            return s

        P = [[False] * len(s) for i in range(len(s))]

        for i in range(len(s)):
            P[i][i] = True

        for i in range(len(s) - 1):
            P[i][i + 1] = (s[i] == s[i + 1])

        for s_len in range(3, len(s) + 1):
            for i in range(len(s) + 1 - s_len):
                P[i][i + s_len - 1] = P[i + 1][i + s_len - 2] and (s[i] == s[i + s_len - 1])

        ip = 0
        jp = 0
        max_len = 1

        for i in range(len(s)):
            for j in range(len(s)):
                if P[i][j] and j + 1 - i > max_len:
                    max_len = j + 1 - i
                    ip = i
                    jp = j
                    continue

        return s[ip:jp + 1]
```

[image]

- Since the runtimes is high, it's possible that it would fail sometimes.
- I guess LeetCode has a time limit for each problem, maybe 10 seconds would be the limit for this specific problem.
- Probably based on the geolocation/time, the runtime would be different also.

---

#### Just a bit more optimization:

- Please see this line `for j in range(i + 1, len(s)):`:

```
class Solution(object):

    def longestPalindrome(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: str
        """
        if len(s) < 1:
            return s

        P = [[False] * len(s) for _ in range(len(s))]

        for i in range(len(s)):
            P[i][i] = True

        for i in range(len(s) - 1):
            P[i][i + 1] = (s[i] == s[i + 1])

        for s_len in range(3, len(s) + 1):
            for i in range(len(s) + 1 - s_len):
                P[i][i + s_len - 1] = P[i + 1][i + s_len - 2] and (s[i] == s[i + s_len - 1])

        ip = 0
        jp = 0
        max_len = 1

        for i in range(len(s)):
            for j in range(i + 1, len(s)):
                if P[i][j] and j + 1 - i > max_len:
                    max_len = j + 1 - i
                    ip = i
                    jp = j
                    continue

        return s[ip:jp + 1]
```

[image]

- It reduces about 1 second but still not good.
- I'm sure there are more ways to optimize.
- Wait a bit! There are good Python reviewers here. Would likely help you out.

---

#### With some comments:

```
class Solution:
    def longestPalindrome(self, s):
        if len(s) < 1:
            return s

        def isPalindrome(left, right):
            return s[left:right] == s[left:right][::-1]

        # We set the left pointer on the first index
        # We set the right pointer on the second index
        # That's the minimum true palindrome
        left, right = 0, 1

        # We visit the alphabets from the second index forward once
        for index in range(1, len(s)):
            # Here we move the right pointer twice and once checking for palindromeness
            # We boundary check using index - right, to remain positive
            if index - right > 0 and isPalindrome(index - right - 1, index + 1):
                print(f"Step {index - 1}: Left pointer is at {index - right - 1} and Right pointer is at {index + 1}")
                print(f"Palindromeness start: {index - right - 1} - Palindromeness end: {index + 1}")
                print(f"Window length: {right}")
                print(f"Before: Left is {left} and Right is {left + right}")
                left, right = index - right - 1, right + 2
                print(f"After: Left is {left} and Right is {left + right}")
                print(f"String: {s[left: left + right]}")
                print('#' * 50)
            if index - right >= 0 and isPalindrome(index - right, index + 1):
                print(f"Step {index - 1}: Left pointer is at {index - right} and Right pointer is at {index + 1}")
                print(f"Palindromeness start: {index - right - 1} - Palindromeness end: {index + 1}")
                print(f"Window length: {right + 1}")
                print(f"Before: Left is {left} and Right is {left + right}")
                left, right = index - right, right + 1
                print(f"After: Left is {left} and Right is {left + right}")
                print(f"String: {s[left: left + right]}")
                print('#' * 50)
        return s[left: left + right]


Solution().longestPalindrome("glwhcebdjbdroiurzfxxrbhzibilmcfasshhtyngwrsnbdpzgjphujzuawbebyhvxfhtoozcitaqibvvowyluvdbvoqikgojxcefzpdgahujuxpiclrrmalncdrotsgkpnfyujgvmhydrzdpiudkfchtklsaprptkzhwxsgafsvkahkbsighlyhjvbburdfjdfvjbaiivqxdqwivsjzztzkzygcsyxlvvwlckbsmvwjvrhvqfewjxgefeowfhrcturolvfgxilqdqvitbcebuooclugypurlsbdfquzsqngbscqwlrdpxeahricvtfqpnrfwbyjvahrtosovsbzhxtutyfjwjbpkfujeoueykmbcjtluuxvmffwgqjgrtsxtdimsescgahnudmsmyfijtfrcbkibbypenxnpiozzrnljazjgrftitldcueswqitrcvjzvlhionutppppzxoepvtzhkzjetpfqsuirdcyqfjsqhdewswldawhdyijhpqtrwgyfmmyhhkrafisicstqxokdmynnnqxaekzcgygsuzfiguujyxowqdfylesbzhnpznayzlinerzdqjrylyfzndgqokovabhzuskwozuxcsmyclvfwkbimhkdmjacesnvorrrvdwcgfewchbsyzrkktsjxgyybgwbvktvxyurufsrdufcunnfswqddukqrxyrueienhccpeuqbkbumlpxnudmwqdkzvsqsozkifpznwapxaxdclxjxuciyulsbxvwdoiolgxkhlrytiwrpvtjdwsssahupoyyjveedgqsthefdyxvjweaimadykubntfqcpbjyqbtnunuxzyytxfedrycsdhkfymaykeubowvkszzwmbbjezrphqildkmllskfawmcohdqalgccffxursvbyikjoglnillapcbcjuhaxukfhalcslemluvornmijbeawxzokgnlzugxkshrpojrwaasgfmjvkghpdyxt")
```

#### Prints:

```
Step 18: Left pointer is at 18 and Right pointer is at 20
Palindromeness start: 17 - Palindromeness end: 20
Window length: 2
Before: Left is 0 and Right is 1
After: Left is 18 and Right is 20
String: xx
##################################################
Step 25: Left pointer is at 24 and Right pointer is at 27
Palindromeness start: 23 - Palindromeness end: 27
Window length: 3
Before: Left is 18 and Right is 20
After: Left is 24 and Right is 27
String: ibi
##################################################
Step 462: Left pointer is at 460 and Right pointer is at 464
Palindromeness start: 459 - Palindromeness end: 464
Window length: 4
Before: Left is 24 and Right is 27
After: Left is 460 and Right is 464
String: pppp
##################################################
```

#### Happy Coding! ( ˆ_ˆ )

Comment: better than 94%, that's nice!

Comment: I believe `s[left:right][::-1]` can also be `s[right-1:left-1:-1]`.  I presume that would save a bit of time as well.

Comment: @Emma I agree that `s[left:right].reverse()` would be different (and possibly nonsensical).  I'm not seeing how reversing the slice at the same time as slicing would be different than slicing and then reversing.

Comment: @Emma: +1. Many thanks for your insights. I'm still slowly reading your "Alternative Solution". That looks very smart. I have yet "decipher" the two "if" conditions. Could you say a few words about the underlying ideas?

Comment: It is very interesting to see that my code could pass the tests in your snapshot. I have never seen it passed submitting it several times on my own.

Comment: It seems that using the dynamical programming approach mentioned in my question is unlikely to pass the LeetCode tests.